# JQUERY- styling validations

Tags: php, html, css, validation

I have an existing form. I want to change the border colour of the input field from like red to green and display the error message under the put field.

To be more precise, something similar to this:
[image]

Any ideas, and plugins or a way to apply this style to error messages.
I am currently using the following:

```css
.error {
    background-color: #e86065;
    color: black;
    display:inline-block;
    font: 0.5em;
    height: 1.05em;
    }
    
    b#email{
    margin-left: 30px;    
    }

  input#pass1:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

   input#pass1:valid {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

input#pass1:required{
    background:transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
}
```

```html
   <form id="myform " class="Form" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" accept-charset="utf-8">

                <!--                    <div id="first">-->
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="" required >
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $c_emailErr; ?></span>
                <br>

                <figure>
                    <input class ="login-field" type="text" id="pass1" name="pass1" value="" placeholder="Password"  maxlength="30" required>
                    <br>
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $c_pass1Err; ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <input class ="login-field" type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" value="" placeholder=" Confirm password" maxlength="30" required><!--<span class="error"><?php //echo $c_pass2Err;              ?></span>-->
                    <div id="messages"></div>
                </figure>
                <p class="remember_me">
                </p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-default">
                <br>
            </form>
```

PHP

```
  <?php
    $c_emailErr = $c_pass1Err = $c_pass2Err = "";

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $c_email = $_POST['email'];
 $c_pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
 $c_pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

    //Checking the email address
        if (!filter_var($c_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {

        } else {
           $c_emailErr = ("<b> Email is not a valid email address</b>");
        }

        if (strlen($c_pass1) <= '8') {
            $c_pass1Err = "<b>Your Password Must Contain At Least 8 Characters!</br>";
            //check passwords
        } elseif ($c_pass1 == $c_pass2) {



            $q = "INSERT INTO Cus_Register(Cus_Email,Cus_Password,Cus_confirm_password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $c_email, $c_pass1, $c_pass2);
          if ($q) {
                echo "<script> alert('registration sucessful')</script>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<b>Oops! Your passwords do not </b>";
        }
    }

    function clean_input($data) {
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you want it by PHP?

Comment: @divy3993 i really don't mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 $(function(){
  $("#submit").on("click",function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var fname = $("#fname").val();
   if( isNaN(fname) !== false && fname !=="" )
   {
   $("#fname").removeClass("error");
   $("#fname").addClass("success");
   $(".msg").html("<font color='green'>Input with success</font>");
   return false;
   }
   else{
    $("#fname").removeClass("success");
    $("#fname").addClass("error");
    $(".msg").html("<font color='red'>Input with error</font>");
    return false;
   }
 }) 
  });
```

```css
.success{
   border:1px solid green ;
  }
  .error{border:1px solid red ; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Form Shows Dynamic JQuery Validation</h2>
  <form  method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
   <div class="msg"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```